# How to check if a function was called with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I would like to test if a new Apollo server object is created when calling the function `getApolloServer()` below:

```
// src/apolloServer.ts
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server'
import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql'
import { HelloWorldResolver } from './resolvers/HelloWorldResolver'
import { MovieResolver } from './resolvers/MovieResolver'

export const getApolloServer = async () => {
  return new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [HelloWorldResolver, MovieResolver],
    }),
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
  })
}
```

My jest test code looks like this:

```
// src/apolloServer.test.ts
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server'
import { getApolloServer } from './apolloServer'

jest.mock('apollo-server')

describe('Apollo server', () => {
  it('should create a new Apollo server', () => {
    getApolloServer()
    expect(ApolloServer).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

Jest reports `Received number of calls: 0` instead of the expected `1`. I'm new to testing and javascript so I'm probably missing something obvious here but I couldn't find a proper example in the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html) on how to do this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is an async function and so should your test be. Make your unit test async and await on getApolloServer(). Check what is the result of `await getApolloServer()`. That should be an instance of ApolloServer.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobeinstanceofclass